# vim search like in emacs

Tags: vim

Is there a way to search in vim like in emacs?

More precisely, say I start searching with incremental search turned on. The cursor will go to the first match. I hit enter and then 'n' to go to the next match. Now I want to add some characters to my original search expression and search for the next match. I can't do this because after I hit 'enter', the focus leaves the search term area.

The emacs equivalent would be ctrl-s blah ctrl-s ha. And I would end up searching for the term 'blahha'.

Does that make sense? Is it possible?

**Edit**

The ideal situation would be to do something like /blah < C-S >, and have it immediately jump to the second occurance of 'blah', while keeping the focus in the search buffer.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: On the topic of search refinement, you may want to take a look at `q/`. See `:h q/` for more information. Also there is a nice Vimcast about this subject. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to hit `/<C-R>/` then append your new text. `/` will pop open the search dialog, `<C-R>` allows you to paste from one of your registers, and the `/` registers is the previous search buffer, which contains your most recent search text.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might make a mapping for it, like

```
nnoremap <leader>/ /<C-R>/
```

As I mentioned in the other comment, if you want to stay in the search buffer, you could add something like this to your vimrc. I think this will get you what you want.

```
cnoremap <C-S> <CR>/<C-R>/
```

Comment: I'm probably stupid, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: `<C-R>` here means control + R at the same time. If that doesn't work, I'm a bit surprised. I think Tom's answer is probably better anyway.

Comment: Yup. I'm stupid. I hit control-R, but didn't hit the '/' afterwards. Sweet trick. Thanks!

Comment: The suggested edit doesn't work. Hitting C-S while in the search buffer does nothing.

Comment: There must be something special about C-S, since using C-L worked. Superb!

Comment: `<C-s>` is often eaten by the terminal.

Comment: @Alex, you might want to do `:%s/buffer/register/g`.

Comment: I guess using <C-s> was a poor choice. I was just testing in GVim since I'm at work, and it worked fine there. Also, thanks for the correction romainl.

Answer (score 8):

`/<Up>` or `/<C-P>` will get you to your previous seach, and you can continue to type after that to append. You can add `:nnoremap / /<Up>` to your vimrc if you would like this to be your default behaviour.

Comment: This works, but it's still one more keystroke than the ideal. I still have to hit 'enter' after entering the original search and then '/' to search again :)

Comment: Try adding `cnoremap <C-S> <cr>/<up>` to your vimrc. I think that will do what you're asking.

Comment: The .vimrc change doesn't do much. Same with Alex's. Perhaps my C-S isn't recognized as such. Or I'm not putting it in the proper place, even though it's right smack between two nnoremap directiv lines.

Comment: Thanks for help!! Works with <C-L>. This would be a prime time for a double accept feature :-/ Unfortunately you lost a coin toss.

Comment: Ah, you may have <C-S> getting remapped to Save (say, you're on Windows and using the default setup).  You can check your mappings by executing `:map <C-S>`